# Dynamic canvas chart with jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jquery-ui-slider, canvasjs

I am using a canvas library for creating a dynamic chart to see the overflowing data using jquery UI-scroll, But the scrollbar always coming on the left-hand side If a user wants to see initial plotted data they need to scroll it to the left-hand side. But I need a scrollbar always in the right.

```
var scrollbar = $(".scroll-bar").slider({
  max:6,
  min:0,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {

  }
});
```

Please find my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/082at1u5/

Answer (score 0):

CanvasJS has recently released StockChart which comes with inbuilt slider. Please check this resource (https://canvasjs.com/docs/stockcharts/stockchart-options/navigator/slider/) for more information.

Also, please check this example for a dynamic chart with slider - https://canvasjs.com/javascript-stockcharts/dynamic-stockchart-navigator/